# Java SocketException: Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение

Tags: java, h2

Я пытаюсь подключиться к H2 database в режиме сервера.
Сам сервер запускается:
[image: Терминал]

Однако при попытке создания подключения из кода выдаёт следующее исключение:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Соединение разорвано: "java.net.SocketException: Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение: localhost:9092"
Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketException: Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение: localhost:9092" [90067-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:678)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:212)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:437)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:325)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:122)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:59)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
    at sql.demo.StockExchange.main(StockExchange.java:13)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:325)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:263)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:393)
    at org.h2.value.Transfer.readInt(Transfer.java:270)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:603)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:163)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:433)
```

Сам код:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

URL базы: `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/C:/Users/Nikita/Documents/java/SQLDemo/db`

Проверял порт 9092 через cmd, вроде подключение есть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отключение брандмауэра не помогло, другой внятной информации в существующих вопросах не нашёл

Comment: база данных h2 принимает только локальные соединеня, а удаленные не принимает.

Comment: @RomanC разве я удалённо соединяюсь? Сервер ведь localhost создаётся

Comment: Зачем задавать невнятный вопрос?

Comment: а какой url указываете для подключения?